# MySQL Join with condition when matching certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a MySQL database with tables `countries` and `exchange_rates`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM countries;
+----------------+----------+----------------+
| name           | currency | GDP            |
+----------------+----------+----------------+
| Switzerland    | CHF      |   163000000000 |
| European Union | EUR      | 13900000000000 | 
| Singapore      | SGD      |   403000000000 |
| USA            | USD      | 17400000000000 |
+----------------+----------+----------------+
mysql> SELECT * FROM exchange_rates;
+----------+------+
| currency | rate |
+----------+------+
| EUR      |  0.9 |
| SGD      | 1.37 |
+----------+------+
```

I would like to have a joined table with additional column showing GDP in US$.

Currently I have this:

```
mysql> SELECT countries.name, GDP, countries.GDP/exchange_rates.rate AS 'GDP US$'
    -> FROM countries, exchange_rates
    -> WHERE exchange_rates.currency=countries.currency;
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| name           | GDP            | GDP US$        |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| European Union | 13900000000000 | 15444444853582 |
| Singapore      |   403000000000 |   294160582917 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

However, I would like to additionally show:

- GDP in local currency, even if exchange rate information is missing
- GDP for countries with local currency 'USD' in both columns

The desired output is:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| name           | GDP            | GDP US$        |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| European Union | 13900000000000 | 15444444853582 |
| Singapore      |   403000000000 |   294160582917 |
| Switzerland    |   163000000000 |                |
| USA            | 17400000000000 | 17400000000000 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Simple rule: NEVER use comma-join syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `left join` to include countries with missing exchange rates, and a case expression to always set USA GDP to USA GDP:

```
SELECT 
    c.name, 
    GDP, 
    CASE WHEN c.name = 'USA' THEN c.GDP ELSE c.GDP/er.rate END AS 'GDP US$'
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates er ON er.currency = c.currency;
```

Also, I changed to proper joins and added aliases for the tables to shorten the query a bit.

Comment: Excellent! However, it is safer to use `WHEN c.currency='USD'`

Comment: @Roman Yes it might be if the name could change, but I'm guessing it won't :)

Comment: @Roman If you intend to always use USA as base a better option might be to simply insert a row in exchange_rates for ('USD', 1), much like the answer by Nir Levy. Then you wouldn't have to use a case expression or do any subquery.

Comment: In reality I have data series, therefore I would need to insert many rows, which bring no additional information. Besides, there are countries other than USA with USD as official currency.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get #1, you just need to use `left join` instead of inner join:

```
SELECT countries.name, GDP, countries.GDP/exchange_rates.rate AS 'GDP US$'
  FROM countries LEFT JOIN exchange_rates
  ON exchange_rates.currency=countries.currency;
```

In order to get #2, just add to the exchange_rate table a record for USD with rate 1. If you don't want it in the table, do it in the query:

```
SELECT countries.name, GDP, countries.GDP/full_exchange_rates.rate AS 'GDP US$'
  FROM countries LEFT JOIN (
   select currency, rate from exchange_rates
    union
   select 'USD' as currency, 1 as rate 
  ) as full_exchange_rates
ON full_exchange_rates.currency=countries.currency;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine, but I would write this as:

```
SELECT c.name, c.GDP, c.GDP/COALESCE(er.rate, 1.0) AS "GDP US$"
FROM countries c LEFT JOIN
     exchange_rates er
     ON er.currency = c.currency;
```

I think the `COALESCE()` is the easiest method . . . assuming that the only missing exchange rate is USD.

Comment: As you may have noticed, 'USD' is NOT the only one missing. Nevertheless, thanks for a nice idea. It fits perfectly to one of my other situations